# jQuery - Display image next to mouse cursor only when certain HTML attribute is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, hover

I currently have an image displaying when the mouse hovers over a div...
but i only what the image to display next to the mouse if a "div" has a HTML property of "align="center" and if it doesn't then i don't want the image to display?

I think i'm quiet close but i can't figure out how to call the var "divalign" attribute, spent all last night on it :S

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $("#MainImage");
    $img.hide();
    var divalign = $("div").attr("align="center");
    $('div').mousemove(function(e) {
        $img.fadeIn(0);
        $img.offset({
            top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight()-2,
            left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth()-18)
        });
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $img.fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
  $('div').mousemove(function(e) {
      if ($(this).attr('align') === 'center') {
        // only show if the align attribute has value center
        $img.fadeIn(0);
        $img.offset({
            top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight()-2,
            left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth()-18)
        });
      }
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $img.fadeOut(250);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have error in this line

```
 var divalign = $("div").attr("align="center");
```

Change that to

```
 var divalign = $("div").attr("align","center");
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner, if you could give these DIVs a class name (ex: class="alignCenter"), then register the event handler on those divs.

```
$('div.alignCenter').on('mousemove', function(e) {
     ..........................
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div[align="center"]').mousemove(function(e) {
        $img.fadeIn(0);
        $img.offset({
            top: e.pageY - $img.outerHeight()-2,
            left: e.pageX - ($img.outerWidth()-18)
        });
      }
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $img.fadeOut(250);
    });
```